# Java mail api on Linux

Tags: java, linux, email, exception

I try to connect to a mailserver via javax.mail and "imap".

This code works perfectly fine on Windows, but when i try it on Linux, it doesen't work.

```
public static void init() {
    try {
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        store = session.getStore("imaps");
        store.connect("imap.gmx.net", user, password);

        System.out.println(store);
        javax.mail.Folder[] folders = store.getDefaultFolder().list("*");
        int i = 0;
        folderS = new String[folders.length];
        for (javax.mail.Folder folder : folders) {
            if ((folder.getType() & javax.mail.Folder.HOLDS_MESSAGES) != 0) {
                folderS[i] = (folder.getFullName() + ": " + folder.getMessageCount());
                System.out.println(folderS[i]);
            }
            i++;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If i run the code on a Linux system i get an exception:

> javax.mail.MessagingException: java.lang.IllegalStateException;
>   nested exception is:  javax.net.ssl.SSLException:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException   at
>   com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:735)   at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)  at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)  at
>   Help.MailController.init(MailController.java:30)  at
>   GUI.Starter$1$1.run(Starter.java:14) Caused by:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.IllegalStateException   at
>   sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1906)     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1889)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1410)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:598)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:372)
>     at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:238)
>     at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.(Protocol.java:123)  at
>   com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.(IMAPProtocol.java:126)
>     at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.newIMAPProtocol(IMAPStore.java:756)
>     at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:691)
>     ... 4 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException   at
>   sun.security.ec.ECDHKeyAgreement.deriveKey(Native Method)     at
>   sun.security.ec.ECDHKeyAgreement.engineGenerateSecret(ECDHKeyAgreement.java:130)
>     at
>   sun.security.ec.ECDHKeyAgreement.engineGenerateSecret(ECDHKeyAgreement.java:163)
>     at javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.generateSecret(KeyAgreement.java:648)
>     at sun.security.ssl.ECDHCrypt.getAgreedSecret(ECDHCrypt.java:102)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverHelloDone(ClientHandshaker.java:1061)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:348)
>     at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1026)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:961)   at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
>     at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
>     ... 12 more

Thanks for you help.